# i am unable to publish new app to my console the button for "accept the play app signing terms of service" is disabled. Tell me what should I do

Tags: python, android, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIW87.jpg)

I was trying to publish app to my console which already has two apps live since some months but i cannot publish it because the button for accept the play app signing terms of service button was disabled. I don't know why this happened please give me solution